# Regex to continue matching the similar pattern

Tags: java, regex

I have JCL statement to be matched with regex pattern
The statement would be like below

```
//name JOB optionalParam,keyword=param,keyword=param,keyword=param
```

Actual statement would be like below

```
//ADBB503  JOB ,MSGCLASS=2,CLASS=P 

//ABCD JOB Something,MSG=NTNG,CLASS=ABC
```

I have tried a regular expression to match in groups but the last keyword and param will have n number of times I need to continue matching till it exists.

```
String regex= (\/\/)(\w+)(\s+)(JOB)(\s+)(\w+)?(,)([\w+=\w+]+);
```

My trial is in the link given below
https://regex101.com/r/gUyRMV/1

The error I am facing is only one keyword=parameter is matching. N number of keyword and parameters needs to be matched.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could match the job statement in the first capturing group and make use of `\G` to get the parameters in group 2:

```
(?:(//\w+\s+JOB(?: \w+)?)\h*|\G(?!^)),(\w+=\w+)
```

**Explanation**

- `(?:` Non capturing group

  - `(` Capture **group 1**

    - `//\w+\s+JOB` Match `//`, 1+ word chars and `JOB`
    - `(?: \w+)?` Match optional param
  - `)`\h*` Close group and match 0+ horizontal whitespace chars
  - `|` Or
  - `\G(?!^)` Assert position at the end of previous match, not at the start
- `)`, Close non capturing group and match `,`
- `(` Capture **group 2**

  - `\w+=\w+` Match 1+ word chars `=` 1 + word chars
- `)` Close group

In java

```
String regex = "(?:(//\\w+\\s+JOB(?: \\w+)?)\\h*|\\G(?!^)),(\\w+=\\w+)";
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/0j3ftt/1) | [Java demo](https://ideone.com/PyppWr)

Comment: Solved the problem.

Comment: As explained in the problem this is a jcl statement. Anything apart from matching content is there I need to throw that content and say this is not a valid content. Need to check which content is invalid and throw it. How to handle it in java? any lead will help

Comment: Yes, I need to throw out non matching words as an error content

Comment: @kiranNswamy You could try an approach like this and capture non key value pairs in a different group https://regex101.com/r/wPe2QL/1

Comment: Works exactly as expected.